# how to print location of user using google maps

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a form in which user enter his details along with his address.
Address field is a text box.

I want to have a link(use current location) next to Address text box, when clicked, this link will populate Address text box with user's current location.

I am new to php and google map API, Please suggest how can i achieve this.

TIA,

---

```
I found this example but i am not sure how to populate textbox with address.
http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/RaL8Q/

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '//www.google.com/jsapi',
        dataType: "script",
        success: function(){
            var location = google.loader.ClientLocation;
            if (location) {
                $('#result').append('Estimated city: ' + location.address.city + '<br>Estimated region: ' + location.address.region + '<br>Estimated country: ' + location.address.country   + '<br>Estimated LatLng: ' + location.latitude + ', ' + location.longitude);
            }else{
                $('#result').append('no location found');
            }
        }`enter code here`
    });
});



my Address textbox has below code:
 <li>
       <h2><?php echo __('Address','SampleTheme'); ?>:</h2>
        <p><input type="text" size="50" class="do_input"  name="ad_location_addr" value="<?php echo !isset($_POST['ad_location_addr']) ? 
        get_post_meta($pid, 'Location', true) : $_POST['ad_location_addr']; ?>" /> 
        <?php do_action('SampleTheme_step_after_addr_field');  ?>
        </p>
 </li>
```

Comment: No time for a complete answer now but you might want to check this link: http://www.benmarshall.me/reverse-geocoding-html5-google/

Comment: Thanks Julien,Its very helpful.